# how can you group results in a datatable

Tags: visualforce, datatable

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to group records that are displayed in a datatable in a type of hierarchical structure?

Here is the apex code:

```
public List<Deal__c> deals_to_be_reviewed { get; private set; }

for (Deal__c d : [SELECT IOI_Date__c, IOI_Internal__c, Stage__c, Deal_Team_Members__c, Portfolio_Type__c, Deal_Company__c, Deal_Company__r.Name, Add_On_Company__r.Name, Referral_Company__r.Name, LTM_EBITDA__c, LTM_Revenue__c, Call_Owner_Queue_By__c, Deal_Id_Display__c, Date_Entered__c, Status__c FROM Deal__c WHERE Status__c = 'Active' ORDER BY IOI_Date__c ASC, Stage__c DESC, IOI_Internal__c, Portfolio_Type__c, Deal_Id_Display__c]){
        if ((d.Stage__c == 'Received Information' || d.Stage__c == 'Non-Book Deal-Research In Progress' || d.Stage__c == 'Owner Call Made' || d.Stage__c == 'Call Owner Queue') && (d.Deal_Team_Members__c != null ? !d.Deal_Team_Members__c.contains('TBA') : TRUE)){// && d.Call_Owner_Queue_By__c != null)){
            deals_to_be_reviewed.add(d);
        }
}
```

here is the vf code:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!deals_to_be_reviewed }" var="d" width="100%"  styleClass="summaryTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" columnsWidth="7%,7%,12%,7%,6%,17%,17%,9%,9%,6%">
    <apex:column headerValue="IOI Date">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.IOI_Date__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="IOI Internal">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.IOI_Internal__c}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!IF(d.IOI_Internal__c, '(HKW)', NULL)}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Deal Stage">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.Stage__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="TranX Team">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.Deal_Team_Members__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Port Type">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.Portfolio_Type__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Target Company">
        <apex:outputText value="{!IF(d.Portfolio_Type__c == 'Add On', d.Deal_Company__r.Name + ' (' + d.Add_On_Company__r.Name + ')', d.Deal_Company__r.Name)}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Referral Source">
        <apex:outputText value="{!d.Referral_Company__r.Name}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="LTM EBITDA">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.LTM_EBITDA__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="LTM Revenues">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.LTM_Revenue__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Deal ID">
        <apex:outputField value="{!d.Deal_ID_Display__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

So, basically, for all records that are an "Add On", group those records by the "Add On Company" and then display the "Deal Company" underneath in a hierarchical structure.

In the 6th column, I'd like to group those records and display in a hierarchical structure.  Is there a way to accomplish that in a datatable without completely re-writing the vf page?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you only want to group within the "Add On" category?  Have you tried multiple field expressions in the "order by"?  I'm not sure what happens if one of the fields is null in such a case, but multiple "order by" field expressions are allowed.

Comment: I am using order by, but what I'm trying to do is more like a nested table to create the hierarchy.  So, let's say you have "Acme" as the add on company and there were two records where that existed and the deal company for those records where "Company A" and "Company B", then I'd want one record where Acme is the top level and Company A and Company B where the 2nd level underneath Acme.  Does that help explain?

Comment: others have solved this with jQuery treeview and visualforce; google for some sample code and adapt accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I've not studied your query at length, but have you tried restructuring it to use "Group By" clauses? That would be the only way I know of to to create the groups without sorting your query results in your controller before sending them to your page in a format it can process.

Ultimately, I think you're going to want to use sub-tables to display your sub groups to get it to display properly. This is really no different than what you might do with quotes or invoices that contain bundles of several product items. In essence, think in terms of creating a wrapper class for your results.

Comment: Thanks crmprogdev, I had the feeling it was going to require re-architecting the code using a nested table structure.  By chance, you don't have a simple example do you or could point me to an example online?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have anything simple or that I'm free to post. Think in terms of creating a new class based on the groups you'll be creating/querying. This essentially gets passed to your page as a wrapper using the new class name. Some of the individual variables are going to be contained in the Groups you create, so depending on how you structure it, you'll likely need to iterate on them within the wrapper. I've done this when creating custom quote PDF generators.